# (react.js) dont lose position on screen when re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll in react - but going up, not down.

The component involved is rendering log files, but just one offset at a time. When you first land on the page, only the last offset is fetched and displayed, and as you scroll up, I'm fetching the previous offset from my DB, prepending the new text to the current text, and then re-rendering.

The issue I'm running into is that when it re-renders, I lose the position of the current section of the log I'm viewing, and instead it jumps much higher up with the new log lines.

The best solution I can think of is to keep track of where the user is when it is about to re-render, then calculate what the additional height is/will be from the new fetch, and then just using a window.scrollTop move to the correct position.

I was hoping for something simpler, anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: imo I don't think there is a simpler way, have you considered appending to the list instead of prepending and avoiding this? I think it'll be messy to wait for a render and measure height and it'll probably not be a seamless adjustment?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, appending won't really work in this case though because the idea is that you are viewing a log file - that may also be active and tailing, so if it is active, the lines will be appended and if you page up you will view older log lines that are prepended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use scrollIntoView. It will keep the currently selected element at the top of the viewscreen.

```
componentDidUpdate = () => { if ((this.props.index == this.props.selected)) ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).scrollIntoView(); }
```

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the issue. There is only one component that is updating with new props, I dont want to be at the top of that component, I want to stay with the current line of text that is showing before additional text is prepended to the incoming props and rendered.

Comment: If you are pulling records from your db why would you not display them as individual elements (ie one line component for each).

Comment: how would I keep reference to the selected element however if I'm re-rendering? As react will render all the components again, including my new components, how do I keep track of the element?

Comment: You will need to use onClick to set the current item selected. The parent will have an onClick method that is sent to the line component as a prop. You will probably want a unique id for each line then just check if the current id is equal to the selected id as in the example. (this.props.selectedID == item.id)